# change inputAccessoryView's height issue in iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, swift

I made a MessageComposerView like this
[image]

```
import UIKit

protocol MessageComposerDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
func messageDidChange(messageView: MessageComposerView, height: CGFloat)
func postMessage(message: String)
}

private let maxTextViewHeight: CGFloat = 100.0

class MessageComposerView: UIView, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textView: SAMTextView!
@IBOutlet weak var sendButton: UIButton!

weak var delegate:MessageComposerDelegate?

@IBAction func sendButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.postMessage(textView.text)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    let borderColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1).CGColor
    let layer = CALayer()
    layer.backgroundColor = borderColor
    layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds), 1.0)
    self.layer.addSublayer(layer)

    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    textView.layer.borderColor = borderColor
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    textView.delegate = self
    textView.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = false

    sendButton.backgroundColor = Color.Red.colorValue
    sendButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    sendButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
}

//MARK: TextViewDelegate
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    self.sendButton.enabled = !self.textView.text!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()).isEmpty
    textView.scrollEnabled = textView.contentSize.height >= maxTextViewHeight
    let height = textView.scrollEnabled ? textView.contentSize.height : textView.intrinsicContentSize().height
    delegate?.messageDidChange(self, height: min(height, maxTextViewHeight) + 16.0)
    if let selectedTextRange = self.textView.selectedTextRange {
        let caretRect = self.textView.caretRectForPosition(selectedTextRange.end);
        let height = self.textView.textContainerInset.bottom + caretRect.size.height
        self.textView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(caretRect.origin.x, caretRect.origin.y, caretRect.size.width, height), animated: true)
    }
}
}
```

and in the ViewController when I increase the height of MessageComposerView:

```
func messageDidChange(messageView: MessageComposerView, height: CGFloat) {
    messageView.bounds.size.height = height
    self.reloadInputViews()
    messageView.textView.reloadInputViews()
}
```

In iOS 9,It works well.

[image]

but in iOS 8.4,The textView and Button not change their frame rightly

[image]

So What should I do to fix it in iOS 8.4,Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with iOS 8.4?I can't find it.Or what you expect to be.

Comment: The textView and Button not change their frame rightly after MessageComposerView increase it's height